# javascript open tabs in chunks

Tags: javascript, tabs, settimeout, window.open, chunks

I am currently trying to open tabs in chunks with a loop and a recursive call of a function:

```js
open_pix : function()
{
    ...

    for (i=start; i <= rounds; i++) 
    {
        window.open(mp_op.xpathResult.snapshotItem(i).getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href,'');
    }

    ...

    if (flag)
    {
        var t = window.setTimeout( mp_op.open_pix, mp_op.timeoutMS );
    }
```

Unfortunately my script stops working completely after it has opened the first chunk of tabs.
I assume that the script is killed after the browser loaded new tabs, but this can't be right because it would have stopped after the first opened tab.

So what did I do wrong again ?

Comment: yes it is. mp_op is the object that holds everything. open_pix is contained in it.

Comment: seems like an ugly user experience having an app open multiple windows...why would you ever need that in the first place?

Comment: It's a userscript for a imageboard to open pictures in new tabs instead of clicking them open.

Comment: The problem is probably that when the function runs from the timer, it runs without context (ie it doesn't run as *mp_op.open_pix*, but as plain *open_pix*, so none of the internal references will work.  Care to put it into a jsfiddle so people can play with it?

Answer (score 0):

do it in this way

```
   open_pix : function()
    {
        ...
        opner : function () {
           for (i=start; i <= rounds; i++) 
          {
            window.open(mp_op.xpathResult.snapshotItem(i).getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href,'');
          }

           ...

           if (flag)
           {
             var t = window.setTimeout( mp_op.open_pix, mp_op.timeoutMS );
           }
         }
      opner();
    }
```

so after the open_pix finish exacting the opner function keep work "closures"

Comment: Hmm does not seem to work. It throws me this: function statement requires a name

Comment: ok do it in you way just put the loop inside a function and call this function at the end of open_pix .